# delphi dateformat MM|dd|yy to MM/dd/yy error

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, regional-settings

I need to convert my current date which has the format:

```
     MM|dd|yy     ---  12|09|11
```

I need to convert the format to:

```
     MM/dd/yy     --12/09/11
```

The current system date separator is:

```
   -'|'
```

I use the code as:

```
  var
     sDateOne : TDate ;
 begin
   Label1.Caption:=datetostr(now);              {this display as 12|09|11}
   ShortDateFormat:='MM/dd/yy';
   DateSeparator:='/';
   sDateOne:=StrToDate(Label1.Caption);
   FormatDateTime('MM/dd/yy',sDateOne );
   Label2.Caption:=datetostr(sDateOne);         {this i want as 12/09/11 }
 end;
```

but I get an error at line  sDateOne:=StrToDate(Label1.Caption);
[image]

Please tell me how to convert the date format and display it?

Comment: Note that system locale info may be set by user to use completely different output as default date format you propose. In some cases it is better to keep it consistent for user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is corrected version of your code:

```
var
  DateOne: TDate;
  LocalFormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
begin
  Label1.Caption := datetostr(now);              {this display as 12|09|11}
  DateOne := StrToDate(Label1.Caption);
  GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, LocalFormatSettings);
  LocalFormatSettings.DateSeparator := '/';
  Label2.Caption := FormatDateTime('MM/dd/yy', DateOne, LocalFormatSettings); {this i want as 12/09/11 }
end;
```

For `GetLocaleFormatSettings` information, please see http://delphi.about.com/library/rtl/blrtlGetLocaleFormatSettings.htm

Comment: That works:)
thank you

but why you edited you previuos code?
that was also working for me

Comment: @PresleyDias - You're welcome. Previous version was ok but newer is more safe and universal. PS: In Delphi XE2 (but not 2007) you can also instead of "GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, LocalFormatSettings);" write simply "LocalFormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create;".

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is changing the separator, and not the order of the numbers, then you could simply use `StringReplace()`, eg:

```
var
  S: String;

S := '12|09|11';
S := StringReplace(S, '|', '/', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Comment: nice trick;)
but it would cause problem if i directly do 
'DateOne := StrToDate(now());' <br/>....